# How to calculate the occurrence times of a kind of data through SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a column of status. I want to calculate the number of changes of the status between 0 and 1 through SQL statements.
The data format of the database is similar to the following table:

```
ID    |    SourceName    |    Status    |    SourceType    |    TimeStamp
GUID_1       Jack               1            Manager            2022-01-09
GUID_2       Mark               0            Staff              2022-01-09
GUID_3       Judy               0            Teacher            2022-01-09
GUID_4       Michael            1            Student            2022-01-09
GUID_5       Judy               0            Teacher            2022-01-10
GUID_6       Judy               1            Teacher            2022-01-10
GUID_7       Mark               1            Staff              2022-01-10
GUID_8       Judy               0            Teacher            2022-01-11
GUID_9       Mark               1            Staff              2022-01-11
GUID_10      Jack               0            Manager            2022-01-11
```

ID column is a Random GUID.
The result I expect is:

```
SourceName    |    Count
Jack               1
Judy               2
Mark               1
Michael            0
```

Can SQL statements be implemented? If I can, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Your data has a problem.  The above table is lacking a column which provides the _ordering_ which you think exists (note: without such a column, there is no such order in the table).

Comment: Use [Lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [Lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I didn't write the ID column. I'll modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEAD in a subquery to determine the next value.
You then filter out the rows to when the current status is different from the next status.

To get the count, you can use a conditional sum (IIF or CASE). If the next status isn't null it gets counted.

Sample:

```
SELECT x.SourceName
  , SUM(IIF(NextStatus IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT SourceName
    , Status
    , LEAD(Status) OVER(PARTITION BY SourceName ORDER BY Timestamp)  
  NextStatus
  FROM States
 ) x
WHERE x.NextStatus IS NULL OR x.Status <> x.NextStatus
GROUP BY x.SourceName
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91051/11)

Comment: thanks @Preben Huybrechts ,you solved my problem!